# .NET Dates and JSON

Tags: javascript, .net, json

I want to use this [gist](https://gist.github.com/1868478) to override JQuery's parseJSON to take into account .NET's dates.

The problem is that it does not replace a date in this format:

```
"ReviewDate":"\/Date(1404946800000+0100)\/"
```

This regular expression does not seem to be taking into account the timezone:

```
var replaceNet = /"\\\/Date\((\d+)(?:-\d+)?\)\\\/"/i;
```

Can anybody else suggest how I might fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to format a JSON date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206384/how-to-format-a-json-date)

Comment: @jbabey The question in your link doesn't seem to mention a timezone shift, I think you've done a wrong duplicate report

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following function as formatter:

```
function date(s) { return new Date(parseFloat(/Date\(([^)]+)\)/.exec(s)[1])); }
```

Hope it helps.